# Can't view mega menu after apply product filter in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, products-view

I have a problem with page view, when I apply a filter (i.e : Price, Colours ...etc) the result page begin from footer if I have only a few products, but when I have many results the view begin from middle of the page (I need to scroll up to view the first product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with changing the line from `document.body.scrollTop = 0;` to `document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;` and working perfectly